# .htaccess rewrite www to non-www redirect problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, no-www

So I've been trying to get this redirect code to work for a few hours now and it's driving me crazy. I have the opposite direction (non-www to www) working with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301]
```

I found the above code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013730/redirecting-non-www-to-www

I had to remove the **$1** from the third line of code to get it to work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

What I need is for **www.example.com** to redirect to **example.com**

and for every page on **www.example.com** to redirect to the exact same url, minus the **www**.

**www.example.com/test** ---> **example.com/test**

**www.example.com/begin.php** ---> **example.com/begin.php**

So on and so forth. Since I had the topmost code section working in the opposite direction, I thought it would be easy to just switch a couple of things around and have it working in a few minutes, but I always end up running into 404s, infinite loops, and what have you. The main problem is that I don't fully understand this part of the code:

```
^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

Any help for an apache greenie? Thanks a million!

---**EDIT**---

I found a code that is closer to what I want, but it has its own share of problems. The code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

There are two problems with this code:

1) When I type in **example.com/test**, it first passes through **www.example.com/test**, which I would like to avoid if at all possible.

2) When I type in **example.com/test**, it ends up at **example.com/test.php**, and I would like to avoid having the file with the **.php** extension as the final destination. Any suggestions?